# Solvency II Assets-D1 - aggregation of line items by CIC code

Tags: solvency-ii

The revised version of Assets D1 (now **S.06.02 – List of assets** under CP13) requires the following aggregations ([page 24](http://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/Leitfaden/dl_lf_solvency_guidelines_submission_of_information_061113.pdf?__blob=publicationFile)):

- CIC 71 (Cash), only one line per currency is to be reported;
- CIC 72 (Transferable deposits (cash equivalents)), only one line per pair(bank, currency) is to be reported;
- CIC 73 (Other deposits short term (less than one year)), only one line
  per pair(bank, currency) is to be reported;

CIC codes however are prefixed with a country code.  So my question is - should this report have just ONE line per currency, or one line per currency per XX71 code?  (and similarly for the other points..).  If the former, then how should the CIC code be represented?  (presumably 'CIC71').

EDIT:  I don't see how this can be 'one line per currency' - as we also need to split between Life / Nonlife and RFFs..  Also, would 'look through' cash balances be aggregated too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found on page 10 of [CP-14-052](https://eiopa.europa.eu/Publications/Consultations/EIOPA_EIOPA-CP-14-052_ITS_Reg_Supervisory_reporting.pdf) (released 27 November 2014):

> Unless otherwise stated, each asset shall be reported separately in as
>   many lines as needed in order to properly fill in all variables
>   requested.